# Why Silverlight popup hangs while doing calculations?

Tags: silverlight, popup

I have create a custom date time control in silver light , in my silver light custom control there is property names "EditDate" this date is set with the help of binder , and basically doing two way binding , when i set edit date from date time picker , it well set my external property and while setting external property there is a setter event which performs some calculations , now the issue is while the calculation is in progress my date time picker popup remain opened , is there any way i can hide it immediately after setting "EditDate" ?

Thanks 
Aman.

Comment: Minimal examples are useful to understand what is going on. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the calculations are freezing up the UI thread.  Put the calculations in a BackgroundWorker so the UI can be updated as the calculations are being processed.

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
//Will fire when backgroundworker starts
bw.DoWork += (snd, arg) =>
    {
        //Do your calculations here
        CalculationsFunction(param1, param2)
        //Cannot access UI elements here
    };
//Will fire when backgroundworker finishes
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, arg) =>
    {
        //Can access the UI here again if needed
        if (arg.Error != null)
        {
            //Show message if error
        }
        else
        {
            //Update UI here if needed
        }               
    };
    //Begins running the background worker
    bw.RunWorkerAsync((this.DataContext as Iteration));
```